# Closing shortcode in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I made a simple WordPress plugin which highlights text.

```
add_shortcode('close-span', 'highlighter_closing_span_shortcode');
function highlighter_closing_span_shortcode($atts) {
    return '</span>';
}
```

It's the closing shortcode part of the plugin. In this case, users must type "[close-span]". I want to change it to "[/span]". How can I modify the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$content` parameter of the shortcode to allow users to put copy between tags:

```
add_shortcode( 'span', 'my_span_shortcode' );
function my_span_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ){
    return '<span class="highlighted">' . $content . '</span>';
}
```

You would use the shortcode like this:

```
[span]This will be highlighted[/span]
```

and that would result in:

```
<span class="highlighted">This will be highlighted</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Peter (would comment if I could) this may go without saying but have you tried

```
add_shortcode('/span', 'highlighter_closing_span_shortcode');
function highlighter_closing_span_shortcode($atts) {
return '</span>';
}
```